# LLBLGen: Auto generate DTO files

Tags: c#, orm, llblgenpro, llblgen

In my project I am using LLBLGen as ORM. I am able to generate entity objects for all the tables present in database but respective DTO objects are not getting generated automatically for all the table. I have to manually select each table and generate. Is there any automatic way to do this in one go? LLBLGen version used: 5.2

Answer (score 0):

DTO Model is a **Derived Model** in LLBLGen. You have to create Derived Model in you LLBLGen Designer. You add the DTO you want based on some entity, you repeat the process to add all the necessary DTOs you need.

Then when you generate code, you have the option to generate that specific Derived Model, which include all your DTOs.

More info:

- [Derived Models](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/5.2/Designer/Concepts/DerivedModels.htm)
- [Available Derived Model Frameworks (Reference)](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/5.2/Designer/Functionality%20Reference/AvailableDerivedModelFrameworks.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know how to create a Derived Model and add DTO. But there I have to manually create DTO for each entity. I have more than 100 entities. Is there some automatic way using which I can create DTO's for all the entries in one go?